# Swift 3 Array extension error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to insert 0 always to the array at 0th index, I am trying to write extension on array. But giving some error like :

> Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(Int, at: Int)'

**Here is my code**

```
extension Array {
    mutating func printWithZero() -> Array
    {
        self.insert(0, at: 0)
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your extension, as you have defined it, applies to arrays of all types.  Unfortunately, it isn't possible to insert a `0` into just any array.  You can't, for instance, insert `0` into a `[String]`.

You need to make this extension work only with arrays that can contain the integer literal `0`.  You can do this by adding a constraint on the `Element` type of the array that specifies that the type is `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`:

```
extension Array where Element: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    mutating func printWithZero() -> Array
    {
        self.insert(0, at: 0)
        return self
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = a.printWithZero()

print(a)  // [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(b)  // [0, 1, 2, 3]

// Works with an array of Doubles too

var c = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
let d = c.printWithZero()

print(c)  // [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
print(d)  // [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this simple code, no extension - Swift 3:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3]
myArray.insert(0, at: 0)

print(myArray)  // [0,1,2,3]
```